# initial_sparsity parameter in sparsity.PolynomialDecay() TensorFlow 2.0 magnitude-based weight pruning

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I was trying the tutorial [TensorFlow 2.0 Magnitude-based weight pruning with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/pruning_with_keras#train_a_pruned_mnist)
and came across the parameter *initial_sparsity*

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
from tensorflow_model_optimization.sparsity import keras as sparsity
import numpy as np

epochs = 12
num_train_samples = x_train.shape[0]
end_step = np.ceil(1.0 * num_train_samples / batch_size).astype(np.int32) * epochs
print('End step: ' + str(end_step))

pruning_params = {
      'pruning_schedule': sparsity.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.50,
                                                   final_sparsity=0.90,
                                                   begin_step=2000,
                                                   end_step=end_step,
                                                   frequency=100)
}
```

The tutorial says:

> The parameter used here means:
>
> **Sparsity** PolynomialDecay is used across the whole training process. We start at the sparsity level 50% and gradually train the
>   model to reach 90% sparsity. X% sparsity means that X% of the weight
>   tensor is going to be pruned away.

My question is, shouldn't you start with **initial_sparsity** of 0% and then prune 90% of the weights off?

What does starting with **initial_sparsity** of 50% mean? Does this mean that 50% of the weights are pruned to begin with and then 90% sparsity of pruning is achieved?

Also, for **tfmot.sparsity.keras.ConstantSparsity**, the API is as follows:

```
pruning_params_unpruned = {
    'pruning_schedule': sparsity.ConstantSparsity(
        target_sparsity=0.0, begin_step=0,
        end_step = 0, frequency=100
    )
}
```

> Initializes a Pruning schedule with constant sparsity.
>
> Sparsity is applied in the interval [begin_step, end_step] every
>   frequency steps. At each applicable step, the sparsity(%) is constant.

Does this mean that if a neural network model is already at a sparsity level of 50%, but the *target_sparsity = 0.5* then will the pruning schedule do:

1. No pruning, since the model is already at a pruned level of 50%
2. It further prunes 50% of the weights of the already (50% pruned) model

You can read about it in [PolynomialDecay](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/PolynomialDecay) and in [ConstantSparsity](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/ConstantSparsity)

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

So I also found the Tensorflow documentation on weight pruning to be quite *sparse*, so I spent some quality time with the debugger to figure out how everything works.

## How Pruning Schedules Work

At the most basic level, the Pruning Schedule is simply a function that takes the step as an input and produces a sparsity percentage. That sparsity value is then used to generate a mask, which is used to prune out weights with an absolute value less than then the *k - 1* value given by the absolute value weight distribution and the sparsity percentage.

## PolynomialDecay

Class definition: [Github Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/c2642e5de64bb7709310bd7775de84b4765b359a/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_schedule.py#L183)
The comments included with the class definition above helped me understand how the PolynomialDecay scheduler works.

> Pruning rate grows rapidly in the beginning from initial_sparsity, but then
>       plateaus slowly to the target sparsity.
>
> The function applied is
>
> current_sparsity = final_sparsity + (initial_sparsity - final_sparsity)
>             * (1 - (step - begin_step)/(end_step - begin_step)) ^ exponent

By the above equation, when `step == begin_step` then `current_sparsity = initial_sparsity`. Thus, the weights will be pruned to the `initial_sparsity` on the step specified by the `begin_step` parameter.

I would agree with your assessment, in that you would usually want to start pruning at a lower sparsity than 50%, but I do not have any published research I can cite to backup that claim. You may be able to find more information in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01878) cited with the PolynomialDecay class definition, although I have not had a chance to read it myself.

## ConstantSparsity

Class definition: [Github Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/c2642e5de64bb7709310bd7775de84b4765b359a/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_schedule.py#L137)
The purpose of this scheduler appears to be pretty limited. With every valid prune step, the `target_sparsity` is returned. As such, multiple pruning steps are very much redundant. The use case for this scheduler appears to be for a one time prune during training. The ability to prune with this scheduler multiple times is to align it with its parent abstract class and other pruning schedulers.

## Creating Your Own Pruning Scheduler

If the two above schedulers do not float your boat, the abstract class [PruningSchedule](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/c2642e5de64bb7709310bd7775de84b4765b359a/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_schedule.py#L23) exposes an endpoint which makes it very easy to create your own pruning scheduler, as convoluted as it may be. Below is an example I created myself.
Disclaimer: this scheduler is a creation of a 19 year-old college student's imagination and has no basis in any published literature.

```
PruningSchedule = tfmot.sparsity.keras.PruningSchedule

class ExponentialPruning(PruningSchedule):
def __init__(self, rate=0.01, begin_step=0, frequency=100, max_sparsity=0.9):
    self.rate = rate
    self.begin_step = begin_step
    self.frequency = frequency
    self.max_sparsity = max_sparsity

    # Validation functions provided by the parent class
    # The -1 parameter is for the end_step
    # as this pruning schedule does not have one
    # The last true value is a boolean flag which says it is okay
    # to have no end_step
    self._validate_step(self.begin_step, -1, self.frequency, True)
    self._validate_sparsity(self.max_sparsity, 'Max Sparsity')

def __call__(self, step):
    # Sparsity calculation endpoint

    # step is a integer tensor

    # The sparsity returned by __call__ must be a tensor
    # of dtype=tf.float32, so tf.math is required.

    # In the logic below, you can assume that a valid
    # pruning step is passed.

    p = tf.math.divide(
        tf.cast(step - self.begin_step, tf.float32),
        tf.constant(self.frequency, dtype=tf.float32)
    )
    sparsity = tf.math.subtract(
        tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.math.pow(
            tf.constant(1 - self.rate, dtype=tf.float32),
            p
        )
    )

    sparsity = tf.cond(
        tf.math.greater(sparsity, tf.constant(self.max_sparsity, dtype=tf.float32)),
        lambda: tf.constant(self.max_sparsity, dtype=tf.float32),
        lambda: sparsity
    )

    # This function returns a tuple of length 2
    # The first value determines if pruning should occur on this step
    # I recommend using the parent class function below for this purpose
    # The negative one value denotes no end_step
    # The second value is the sparsity to prune to
    return (self._should_prune_in_step(step, self.begin_step, -1, self.frequency),
            sparsity)

def get_config(self):
    # A function required by the parent class
    # return the class_name and the input parameters as
    # done below
    return {
        'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
        'config': {
            'rate': self.rate,
            'begin_step': self.begin_step,
            'frequency': self.frequency,
            'max_sparsity': self.max_sparsity
        }
    }
```

## Using a Pruning Scheduler

If you only would like certain layers to be pruned, rather than all prunable layers, you can call the `prune_low_magnitude` function on a layer which you are adding to your model.

```
prune_low_magnitude = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude
model = keras.models.Sequential()
...
model.add(prune_low_magnitude(keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(0.0001)),
  ExponentialPruning(rate=1/8)))
```

Also make sure to pass a `UpdatePruningStep` instance to the training callbacks:

```
m.fit(train_input, train_labels, epochs=epochs, validation_data=[test_input, test_labels],
  callbacks=[UpdatePruningStep()])
```

Comment: I created my own custom pruning algorithm in numpy